# Java - Check for selection on JList

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to see if my JList `list` is being selected or not?

I say this because I have a JList and JTextfield and when I type "F" in the JList to do a keyevent action.. the letter F gets typed into the JTextField after I focus on it.

For example: Let's say I go to JTextField and type "hi". I go back to my JList and click on selected item and press "F" to delete that from list... well then in JTextField... I would also type "F" even though I am on JList.

Get what I am saying?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot. But I am assuming this isn't suppose to happen? If so, I can whip up a SSCCE later. I'm kinda hurried right now.

Comment: A KeyEvent generated on a JList should NOT be passed to a JTextField. A SSCCE should be whipped up first before you post a question.

Comment: @Dan, don't be rude. As a temporary fix, use a hotkey with a Ctrl or Alt, this way it won't affect the text field.

Comment: @tulskiy: Sorry, he's been rude to before.

Comment: Do you mean you want the keystroke you typed earlier in a JList be displayed in a JTextField when the text field gets focus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getSelectedIndex()` or `isSelectionEmpty()` function of the JList.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `getSelectedIndex()` is the easiest method.

Let's say you have a list of objects `MyClass` which you want to put in the `JList`:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
// myclass.add ....

JList jList = new JList(myClassList.toArray());
```

Now, to get the selected element:

```
function MyClass getSelectedElement(){
    int index = jList.getSelectedIndex();
    if (index < 0){
        System.out.println("Nothing selected.");
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return myClassList.get(index);
    }
}
```